# Dot as a first character ( .90 ) with ngx-mask

Tags: angular, angular15, ngx-mask

I was trying to use ngx-mask in Angular 15 application here is my textbox looks like

`<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="sharePrice" mask="separator.4" separatorLimit="9999999999" [dropSpecialCharacters]="false">`

I want to input .50 but if I am trying to enter that dot before 5 its not appearing. I needed to type 0 to make the dot appear in the textbox ( 0.50 ) but I want to put the dot and then 50 ( just .50 )

My *ngx-mask* version is **15.1**

I am importing it in my app-module like

`providers: [ provideNgxMask() ]`

Am I making any mistake please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use `mask=".00"`.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which [a comment should be used instead of an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173)). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."